# WPF Color Theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF Application to change color themes.

```
ResourceDictionary blueDict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"/Styles/Colors/Blue/BlueColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
ResourceDictionary greenDict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"/Styles/Colors/Green/GreenColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
ResourceDictionary yellowDict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"/Styles/Colors/Yellow/YellowColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
ResourceDictionary genericDict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"/Styles/Colors/GenericColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
```

On the MainWindow I have a ComboBox that stores three enum values "Blue, Green, Yellow". That's what it does when the selected index has changed:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Themes newTheme = (Themes)cbxThemes.SelectedItem;

if (newTheme == currentTheme)
    return;

switch (newTheme)
{
    case Themes.Blue:
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(blueDict);
        break;

    case Themes.Green:
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(greenDict);
        break;

    case Themes.Yellow:
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(yellowDict);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(genericDict);

currentTheme = newTheme;
```

The first time, everything works well and I can choose whatever color I want, but when I change Colors again, nothing happens.

Is there anything that doesn't update in the background?

The code works, if you output the `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` you can even see the new source. Only the UI is not updated.

Comment: How are you referencing the resources in your xaml?

Comment: see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/44e80e86-9c62-4b77-87bc-00997a4796f4/change-in-applicationcurrentresourcesmergeddictionaries-is-not-visually-updating?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

Simply replace

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(yourDictionary);
```

with

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"yourPath.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
```

As often in programming I have no idea why it works but first of all I'm happy. If someone could explain this to me, that'd be great.

Comment: You have add a new resource object into `MergedDictionaries`, so the resource dictionary will update the keys and values, so it was can apply the new values. But it's a bad idea - It's means you will always add a new object, and leave old data that will never be used in the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
Themes newTheme = (Themes)cbxThemes.SelectedItem;
```

with this line:

```
string newTheme = ((ComboBoxItem)cbxThemes.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Ofcourse you'd also need to change how you handle the comparison between newTheme and currentTheme.

If you don't want to use a string, you can convert it to enum by using:

```
Themes newTheme;
Enum.TryParse(((ComboBoxItem)cbxThemes.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), out newTheme);
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'StyleThemes.Themes' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.

I set the cbxThemes.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Themes));
so the items are type of Themes.

Comment: @j.zeddi Then instead of casting to a ComboBoxItem as done above, use: cbxThemes.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: hm... no exception, but still the same Problem.

Comment: yup, that works for me too, but in my case the colors won't update.  
When I go through my code with the debugger everything looks as it should

Comment: @j.zeddi Oh so it pops into the right switch and completes the Add? That's weird. Because you said it works the first time you change colors, but doesn't work after that I assumed the if statement doesn't go through and returns. But if it doesn't and it does Add accordingly, then that's weird.

Comment: according to that MS support ticket i added to the comments application resources act a little different to local resources, resources that support Freezing (like brushes) are frozen when added to a the dictionary, and frozen resources don't refresh if @Hubbs is using local window resources this may be the reason for the different behaviors

Comment: okay, so I tried it with setting the dictionaries as window resources (not application resources) and it worked perfect. So it definitely is about the application resources freezing...